# searching a Char letter by letter

Tags: java

Trying to search for `patterns of letters in a file`, the pattern is entered by a user and comes out as a `String`, so far I've got it to find the first letter by unsure how to make it test to see if the next letter also matches the pattern. 
This is the loop I currently have. any help would be appreciated

```
    public void exactSearch(){
    if (pattern==null){UI.println("No pattern");return;}
    UI.println("===================\nExact searching for "+patternString);
    int j = 0 ; 
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){

        if(patternString.charAt(i) == data.get(i) )
        j++;
        UI.println( "found at " + j) ;


    }
}
```

Comment: sorry wasn't clear i need to find all this instances that occur not just one

Comment: do you want the positions of where the words matches a `pattern`, or you just a need a `list` of all the `substrings` that match your `pattern` ?

Comment: just the position, for example if my pattern was ABC, and the data was AAACABCCCABC, it would print out "found at 4, found at 8

Comment: you mean found at 4 and 9 . correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the first string until you find the first character of the other string. From there, you can create an inner loop and iterate on both simultaneously, like you did. 
Hint: be sure to look watch for boundaries as the strings might not be of the same size.

Comment: how would i iterate over the first string

Comment: The main idea is to have two loops; in the outer loop you'll do what you're doing, but compare your data.get(i) only to patternString.charAt(0), since all you need to know is whether it matches the first character of the pattern. 
The moment you find it, then you will start your inner loop, where you'll test both strings (data and patternString) together, using a new index (the index will be the same for both strings).

Comment: int j = 0;
        int i = 0; 
        while (i < data.size()) { 
              
            if (patternString.charAt(0) == data.get(i)) { 
                if (patternString.charAt(j) == data.get(i)) { 
               j++; 
               i++ ;
               if (j == patternString.length()) { 
                UI.println("Found pattern "
                                   + "at index " + (i));    
            } 
            } 
          
            else { i++;}


       
}
}

Comment: You're getting closer! The index of the outer loop (i), however, should be increased only on the outer loop, otherwise it will move the character position. Try doing a table of values for some simple string, and watch carefulling how the two indexes behave in each loop. I would start with something small, like pattern: "ab" and data string: "cabcab".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :-

```
String a1 = "foo-bar-baz-bar-";  
String pattern = "bar";

int foundIndex = 0;

while(foundIndex != -1) {
    foundIndex = a1.indexOf(pattern,foundIndex);
    if(foundIndex != -1)
    {
        System.out.println(foundIndex);
        foundIndex += 1;
    }

}
```

`indexOf` - first parameter is the pattern string,
second parameter is starting index from where we have to search.

If pattern is found, it will return the starting index from where the pattern matched.

If pattern is not found, `indexOf` will return -1.

Comment: that would work if i only needed to find it once however it needs to search letter by letter and find all instances not just one :) thanks for the help though

Comment: Looks like I couldnot understand you question properly. If data is "foo-bar-baz-bar-" and pattern is "bar", can you please tell me what should be the output ? Also is your pattern a regex  or simple string ?

Answer (score 1):

```
String data = "foo-bar-baz-bar-";
String pattern = "bar";
int foundIndex = data.indexOf(pattern);

while (foundIndex > -1) {
    System.out.println("Match found at: " + foundIndex);
    foundIndex = data.indexOf(pattern, foundIndex + pattern.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request, you can use this algorithm to search for your positions:

1) We check if we reach at the end of the string, to avoid the `invalidIndex` error, we verify if the remaining substring's size is smaller than the `pattern's` length.

2) We calculate the substring at each iteration and we verify the string with the `pattern`.

```
        List<Integer> positionList = new LinkedList<>();
        String inputString = "AAACABCCCABC";
        String pattern = "ABC";

        for (int i = 0 ; i < inputString.length(); i++) {

            if (inputString.length() - i < pattern.length()){
                break;
            }

            String currentSubString = inputString.substring(i, i + pattern.length());
            if (currentSubString.equals(pattern)){
                positionList.add(i);
            }
        }
        for (Integer pos : positionList) {
            System.out.println(pos); // Positions : 4 and 9
        }
```

**EDIT :**

Maybe it can be optimized, not to use a `Collection` for this simple task, but I used a `LinkedList` to write a quicker approach.

Comment: the inpurtstring is a list so cant be substringed

Comment: I'm sure you can create a String from a list, or adapt this solution.